# Highcharts plotlines label events

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to add tooltip to Highcharts plot-line label.

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451549/highcharts-plotband-tooltip-hover-default-styling), but events can be attached to plot-line only.

Is there a way to add mouse over event for plot-line labels as well?

Answer (score 2):

In te very simple way, you can set useHTML as true on the label. Then use jquery to catch element and add action like show/hide tooltip. See simple example.

```
$('.plabel').mouseover(function(){
            displayTooltip('txt', 10);                                
        });

        $('.plabel').mouseout(function(){
            hideTooltip();
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xL7us/4/

Comment: Would you happen to know how to hide and show labels on highchart `plotlines`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38616712/how-to-hide-highchart-plotline-label-until-mouseover