# how I can get a static tooltip on a plotline, highstock?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I found this example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xL7us/)
of the respective question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451549/highcharts-plotband-tooltip-hover-default-styling)

I just do not want the events "mouseout and mouseover", I just want to load from the start, display the label from the beginning.

```
events: {
      //  mouseover: function (e) {
          load: function (e) {
displayTooltip(this.options.tooltipText, this.svgElem.d.split(' ')[1]);
        }/*,
        mouseout: hideTooltip*/
    }
```

I tried to, but I have not been favorable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`An object defining mouse events for the plot line. Supported properties are click, mouseover, mouseout, mousemove`

So there is no load event in plotline events. Only chart has the event `load`. Here's what I implemented in the chart load event: http://jsfiddle.net/xL7us/72/

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that all you are talking about is a plotLine label ?

Reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.plotLines.label